# Thinning a line

Tags: java

I am writing software that detects an images outline, thins it to a "single pixel" thick, then performs operations on the resulting outline. My hope is to eventually get the following:

[image]

I have written software that detects the RGBA colors, converts it to HSB, asks for a limit that sets whether a pixel is an outline or not (typically some value around 0.25, and checking the B (brightness) value), and then stores true or false in a 2-dimensional array of booleans (true is an outline, false is not). This gets me to stage 2 just fine. I am currently stuck on stage 3, and am currently attempting to achieve the following:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/BTs6miR.png]

Here is my current code, where the `outline[][]` variable is the original 2d array of trues/falses (stage 2) and `thinned[][]` is the outline in stage 3.

```
public void thinOutline() {
    thinned = new boolean[outline.length][outline[0].length];
    for (int x = 0; x < thinned.length; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < thinned[0].length; y++) {
            if (x > 0 && x < thinned.length - 1 && y > 0 && y < thinned[0].length - 1)
                if (!thinned[x + 1][y] && !thinned[x - 1][y] && !thinned[x][y + 1] && !thinned[x][y - 1] && outline[x][y])
                    thinned[x][y] = true;
                else
                    thinned[x][y] = false;
            else
                thinned[x][y] = outline[x][y];
        }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just a script that finds borders and then removes them. If that's the case you can just run that very script many times until it doesn't find any borders any more and at that you should have that desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've devised a pretty simple solution that works well enough for my purposes. I have 3 arrays, `outline[][]`, `thinned[][]`, and `thinIteration[][]`. `outline[][]` and `thinned[][]` are both set when an image is loaded as explained in my question (stages 1 and 2). `thinIteration[][]` is then loaded with batches of pixels that need to be thinned and are considered as "border" pixels. The function then erases these pixels, and if it erased *any* pixels, it restarts the method. It continues to do this cycle until it finds no more pixels to thin.

The program knows whether or not to thin a pixel if it is itself an outline pixel, has at least 2 bordering pixels left/right/up/down and at least 2 bordering pixels diagonally, but not more than 3 left/right/up/down and diagonally (which would mean it is a contained pixel)

```
public void thinOutline() {
    boolean didThinIteration = false;
    for (int x = 1; x < originalWidth - 1; x++)
        for (int y = 1; y < originalHeight - 1; y++) {
            int numOfBorders = (thinned[x - 1][y] ? 1 : 0) + (thinned[x + 1][y] ? 1 : 0) + (thinned[x][y + 1] ? 1 : 0) + (thinned[x][y - 1] ? 1 : 0);
            int numOfDiagonals = (thinned[x - 1][y + 1] ? 1 : 0) + (thinned[x + 1][y + 1] ? 1 : 0) + (thinned[x - 1][y - 1] ? 1 : 0) + (thinned[x + 1][y - 1] ? 1 : 0);

            boolean thin = thinned[x][y] && numOfBorders > 1 && numOfBorders < 4 && numOfDiagonals > 1 && numOfDiagonals < 4;

            thinIteration[x][y] = thin;
            if (thin && !didThinIteration)
                didThinIteration = true;
        }

    for (int x = 0; x < originalWidth; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < originalHeight; y++)
            if (thinIteration[x][y])
                thinned[x][y] = false;

    if (didThinIteration)
        thinOutline();
}
```

Comment: Wow... that's quite a lot of boolean conditions ;) Let's suppose the maths are OK, however I have another question: what's the max size of these arrays? Do you have a max size for images?