# Derive functions (polynomials) from points on a 2D plane

Tags: java

As a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333505/thinning-a-line/), I was able to find a photographs outline, thin it, and then receive a 2D plot of points. I am now attempting to derive groups from these points, hoping to turn something akin to the following:

[image: before]

to the following:

[image: afterwithlines]

or the following:

[image: afterwithparabolas]

The rules are that the groups must be functions, which means given any x value, entering it into f(x), you will only receive one y value. Often this means following the vertical line test, but having f(y) result in only one x value will work as well (following the horizontal line test). I am currently using the following:

```
public void loadFunctions() {
    functions.clear();

    thinOutline();

    int i = 0;
    functions.add(new Function());
    for (int y = 0; y < originalHeight; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < originalWidth; x++)
            if (thinned[x][y]) {
                if (functions.get(i).containsX(x)) {
                    functions.get(i).loadPoly();
                    functions.add(new Function());
                    i++;
                }
                functions.get(i).addPoint(x, y);
            }
}
```

This both works and doesn't. All the lines i get follow the vertical line test, but because I iterate from top to bottom, I could get something like this:

[image: uninteded]

instead of this:

[image: intended]

*Note that I am simply asking for the solution to group the points on the plane. I do not require a solution to deriving the functions, that is another problem I have already solved*

Comment: Why would you title your question "Derive functions (polynomials) from points on a 2D plane" if that isn't what you're trying to do?

Comment: Because that is exactly what I am trying to do, but I only require a solution to grouping the points from SO. I am creating questions that can be easily read in the future.

Comment: "I am not attempting to derive polynomials" ~~you

Comment: I hope I satisfied your short temper.

Comment: I was just confused by you saying both that you were and weren't attempting to do something. I didn't mean to seem angry.